# What's the best way to skip giving the full namespace reference to a structure?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I want to declare an array of colors, to be used as 8-bit style sprites.

```
spriteArray = new System.Drawing.Color[2,2] {
{System.Drawing.Color.Red, System.Drawing.Color.Blue},
 {System.Drawing.Color.Blue, System.Drawing.Color.Red}
};
```

It's a pain, and looks verbose writing out the namespace path each time - what would the best way to reduce it to something like:

```
spriteArray = new System.Drawing.Color[2,2]
{{RED, BLUE},
 {BLUE, RED}};
```

be?

Comment: [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)?

Comment: Namespaces are red, directives are blue; stick them up top; less typing for you

Comment: I don't see any `enum` here! `Color` is not an `enum`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel correct, but the resolution will behave the same either way

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - You're right, I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to remove the names *completely* is to add them as local fields, variables or constants. Since `Color` is not an `enum`, you can't use the `const` approach, but you could do:

```
using System.Drawing;
//...
private static readonly Color Red = Color.Red, Blue = Color.Blue;
//...
spriteArray = new[,] {
    { Red, Blue },
    { Blue, Red },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Include a `using` directive at the top of your code file:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Then it's just:

```
spriteArray = new Color[2,2]
{
    { Color.Red, Color.Blue },
    { Color.Blue, Color.Red } 
};
```

Answer (score 3):

declare it on top ?

```
using System.Drawing;

...
spriteArray = new Color[2,2]
  {{Color.Red, Color.Blue},
 {Color.Blue, Color.Red}};
```

or if there is a name conflict, if there is another class with `Color` name, you can:

```
using SysDraw = System.Drawing;
 ...
spriteArray = new SysDraw.Color[2,2]
  {{SysDraw.Color.Red, SysDraw.Color.Blue},
 {SysDraw.Color.Blue, SysDraw.Color.Red}};
```

Comment: @MarcGravell: I *presume* these are constants defined somewhere.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: it could be some custom, app specific color, called Red or Blue, no necessary *exactly* Red and Blue.

Comment: but @Tigran It would be nice if you mention it, it seems OP doesn't have such constants. He's asking for such a thing.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: OP says that his problem is avoid writing long type definitions every time, so it seems that he is able to compile and run his program. He would like to find a way to write less code.

Comment: Yes, OP asks for reducing `System.Drawing.Color.Red` to `RED`. By adding `using System.Drawing;` you can reduce it to `Color.Red` not `RED`. but in your answer you show as `{RED, BLUE}` to make that to work you need field or constant in the same class named as `RED`, `BLUE`. I see that's missing in your answer(though it is obvious OP may or may not know it). Got it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: yes, you are right. corrected. thanks.